# Search multiple indices for an ID efficiently?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I need to get a document but I have no idea what index it is in. I have a bunch of indices for different days; all prefixed with "mydocs-". I've tried:

```
GET /mydocs-*/adoc/my_second_doc

returns "index_not_found_exception"


GET /mydocs-*/adoc/_search
{
"query": {
  "bool":{
    "filter": [{
      "term":{
      "_id": ["my_second_doc"] 
    }
    }]
  }
  }
}

returns all the docs in the index.
```

Now, if I search the specific index I can get the doc. Problem is that I don't always know the index it is in beforehand. So, I'd have to search many, many indices for it (thousands of indices).

```
GET /mydocs-12/adoc/my_second_doc
```

returns the desired doc.

Any ideas on how to do an efficient Get/Search for the doc?

Comment: Have you tried `GET /mydocs-*/adoc/_search?q=_id:my_second_doc` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with :

```
GET mydocs-*/adoc/_search
{
  "query": {
        "term": {
            "_id": "my_second_doc"
        }
   }
}
```

Or more specifically with :

```
GET mydocs-*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
           {
               "term": {
                  "_id": "my_second_doc"
               }
           },
           {
               "term": {
                  "_type": "adoc"
               }
           }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above two queries will find all the documents whose `index` starting with `mydocs-`, `type`  is `adoc` and `id` is `my_second_doc`.